# where are clang c++11 header files

Tags: c++11, clang, mingw-w64, tdm-mingw

I am trying to read and understand some of the c++11 code from clang-3.4. But I couldn't find standard headers. I am using mingw32 and build clang from source to default location at `/usr/local/lib/clang/3.4`.

I tried to look for  and did

```
$ find |grep iostream
```

from that folder and it returned nothing. I can however compile code with  fine.

Where are the clang implementation of c++11? Am I looking at the wrong folder?

--- Update ---

I built clang 3.4 from source under Windows XP 64-bit, using mingw32 (from mingw.org). I configured clang/llmv in MSYS using:

```
./configure --enable-pic --disable-docs --enable-targets=x86,cpp
```

So, I assume that clang is installed to /usr/local/, and indeed find `clang/3.4` under usr/local/lib. But maybe the header files are elsewhere as suggested by the comment, I did another find/grep in the entire MinGW folder (containing MSYS) and still couldn't find the iostream file. The only thing I got was gcc version:

```
$ cd /c/mingw
$ find | grep iostream
./lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/iostream
./mingw32/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/iostream
```

-- Update 2 ---

I tried install libcxx, using cmake

```
cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" ../libcxx-3.4
make
```

, and got the following error:

```
...
[100%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cxx.dir/__/src/support/win32/support.c
pp.obj
d:/temp/tdm/libcxx-3.4/src/support/win32/support.cpp: In function 'size_t wcsnrt
ombs(char*, const wchar_t**, size_t, size_t, mbstate_t*)':
d:/temp/tdm/libcxx-3.4/src/support/win32/support.cpp:134:88: error: 'wcrtomb_s'
was not declared in this scope
             result = wcrtomb_s( &char_size, dst + dest_converted, dest_remainin
g, c, ps);
...
```

Comment: `lib` means library, i.e. compiled code (.a and .so files). Headers live in `include` directories.

Comment: You'll get incomplete answers unless you specify your OS, too.

Answer (score 0):

Clang builds separately from [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), so you need to install it first to get that `<iostream>` include file.

Alternatively, you can instal MinGW, which comes with GNU libstdc++.